# Parametrisation vs Lagrange multipliers of curve

Tags: calculus, curves, lagrange-multiplier, parametrization

I'm given the function
$$f(x,y,z) = xy+yz$$
with the constraints
\begin{align*}
x+y+z=1\quad \wedge \quad x^2+y^2+z^2=6 
\end{align*}
I've tried to determine the extreme values with lagrange multipliers and through parametrisation.

I'm pretty confident with my solution with lagrange multipliers since it's also the solution Wolfram Alpha computes (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find%20extrema%20of%20xy%2Byz%20for%20%20x%2By%2Bz%3D1%2C%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D6))

But when I do parametrisation, I get that
\begin{align*}
&f(x,y,z) = y(x+z) \quad \wedge \quad x+z = 1-y\\
\Rightarrow \quad &f(x,y,z) = y-y^2
\end{align*}
and with the last constraint I get that $-\sqrt{6}\leq y\leq \sqrt{6}$.

The problem is that the maximum value of the two methods matches but the minimum value doesn't.

It's at $y = 1/3 - \sqrt{34}/3$ for lagrange mult. and at $y=-\sqrt{6}$ for parametrisation.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: At $y = \sqrt6, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 6$ gives $x = z = 0$ and that does not fulfill the constraint $x + y + z = 1$

Comment: @MathLover thank you!

Comment: An answer that doesn't use Lagrange multipliers stems from the decomposition:
$$(x+y+z)^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2)=2(xy+yz+zx)$$
Otherwise said:$$1-6=2(f(x,y)+zx) \ \iff \ f(x,y)=-\frac52 - zx$$ Can you take it from here ?